# Using requestAnimationFrame to start and stop a function running three.js inside Barba.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, pjax

My home page is running three.js and I am using barba.js to use ajax for smoother transitions between pages. The problem is that after I have gone back and forth away from the home page and back to it a few times my site starts to run extremely slowly. I am trying to think of a way around this and I thought I had one using barba.js Views and a requestAnimationFrame, however I don't think it helped enough. Does anyone have a better idea of how to either destroy or stop executing my three.js function?

barbaMain.js

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  var lastElementClicked;
  let animationLoop = null

  const SingleNews = Barba.BaseView.extend({
    namespace: 'single-news',
    onEnterCompleted: function () {
        animationLoop = requestAnimationFrame( doThree )
    },

    onLeave: function() {
      cancelAnimationFrame(animationLoop)
    },

  });

  SingleNews.init()

Barba.Pjax.start();






  Barba.Dispatcher.on('linkClicked', function(el) {
    lastElementClicked = el;
  });
  var FadeTransition = Barba.BaseTransition.extend({
    start: function() {

      Promise
        .all([this.newContainerLoading, this.fadeOut()])
        .then(this.fadeIn.bind(this));
    },

    fadeOut: function() {

      return $(this.oldContainer).animate({
          opacity: 0
        }, 400, function() {} ).promise()
    },

    fadeIn: function() {

      var _this = this;
      var $el = $(this.newContainer);

      $(this.oldContainer).hide();

      $el.css({
        visibility: 'visible',
        opacity: 0
      });

      $el.animate({
        opacity: 1
      }, 400, function() {

        _this.done();

      });
    }
  });


  Barba.Pjax.getTransition = function() {

      return FadeTransition;
  };
})
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Jacob Truax Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="canvas-fix">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=IBM+Plex+Mono" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="portfolio.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="barba.js"></script>
  <script src="barbaMain.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="barba-wrapper">
  <div class="barba-container" data-namespace="single-news">
  <header>
  <a class="home" href="#">Jacob Truax</a>
  <a class="contact" href="info.html">Info</a>
  <a class="info" href="#">Work</a>
  </header>

<section class="three"></section>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Three.js functions are all inside this:

```
const doThree = function () {}
```

Comment: this is a SPA? Is it possible some code you haven't shown is adding some sort of event handler multiple times for the same event?

Comment: @Bravo Here is the link to the website that is live now: www.jacobtruax.info

Comment: @Bravo Let me know what more information I need to share and I will edit and add it

Comment: I see your website is written to exclude firefox (i.e. you assume a global variable called `event`, which is an internet explorer non-standard thing that has been "adopted" by Edge and Chrome) - anyway - not going to debug all your code for you. I asked a simple question `Is it possible some code you haven't shown is adding some sort of event handler multiple times for the same event?` - since it's your code, you can add some console.log to show what event handlers are added when

Comment: @Bravo Not that I know of. I thought that it was maybe calling the function doThree everything the page was changed, thats why I tried adding it to an animationframe to be able to stop calling it when going to other pages besides the index.